Prove that $\int_{0}^{\pi} \dfrac{\ln (1 - \lambda^2 \sin^2 x)}{\sin x} \, \mathrm dx = -2 (\sin^{-1} \lambda)^2$ if $0 \leq \lambda \leq 1$.

Prove that
$$\int\limits_{0}^{\pi} \frac{\ln (1 - \lambda^2 \sin^2 x)}{\sin x} \, \mathrm dx = -2 (\sin^{-1} \lambda)^2 \qquad \text{if} \quad 0 \leq \lambda \leq 1.$$

Any hints?

Welcome to MSE. I'd suggest reading this on how to properly ask questions here. Furthermore, you should familiarise yourself with MathJax.
Lastly, you should at least state what you tried yourself. That way, some people might be able to give you good hints on how to approach the problem.

Hint: since both sides are equal if $\lambda=0$, see whether their derivatives with respect to $\lambda$, or $t=\arcsin\lambda$ (a substitution worth making early), are equal too.

Have you tried Leibniz rule?

One method of evaluation is to expand the $\ln(1+x)$ into a series form and then use the Beta function to evaluate the $\sin$ integral. After this is completed then compare the resulting series to that of $ ( \sin^{-1}(x) )^2$ and they should be equal.

First, take into account the symmetry.

$0\leq \lambda\leq 1$,
\begin{align}F(\lambda)&=\int_0^\pi\frac{\ln(1-\lambda^2\sin^2x)}{\sin x}dx\\
&=2\int_0^\frac{\pi}{2}\frac{\ln(1-\lambda^2\sin^2x)}{\sin x}dx\\
F^\prime(\lambda)&=-4\int_0^\frac{\pi}{2}\frac{\lambda\sin x}{1-\lambda^2\sin^2x}dx\\
&=4\left[\frac{\arctan\left(\frac{\lambda\cos x}{\sqrt{1-\lambda^2}}\right)}{\sqrt{1-\lambda^2}}\right]_0^{\frac{\pi}{2}}=-\frac{4\arctan\left(\frac{\lambda}{\sqrt{1-\lambda^2}}\right)}{\sqrt{1-\lambda^2}}\\
&=-\frac{4\arcsin \lambda}{\sqrt{1-\lambda^2}}\\
F(\lambda)&=-4\int_0^\lambda\frac{\arcsin t}{\sqrt{1-t^2}}dt\\
&=\boxed{-2\left(\arcsin\lambda\right)^2}
\end{align}

This question seems not to meet the standards for the site. Instead of answering it, it would be better to look for a good duplicate target, or help the user by posting comments suggesting improvements. Please also read the meta announcement regarding quality standards.

Let's assume that $\lambda = \sin y$
Then, the equation becomes
$\int_{0}^{\pi} \frac{\ln{(1-(\sin x \sin y)^2)}}{\sin x} \; dx$
We can apply Leibniz integral rule, which is described in https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leibniz_integral_rule
Then, The equation becomes
$\frac{\partial}{\partial y} \int \int_{0}^{\pi} \frac{\ln{(1-(\sin x \sin y)^2)}}{\sin x} \;dx \; dy$
$=\int \int_{0}^{\pi} \frac{\partial}{\partial y}\frac{\ln{(1-(\sin x \sin y)^2)}}{\sin x} \;dx \; dy$
$=\int -2 \cos y \int_{0}^{\pi}\frac{\sin x \sin y}{1-(\sin x \sin y)^2} \;dx \; dy$
Using partial fraction expansion
$=\int - \cos y \int_{0}^{\pi}\frac{1}{1-\sin x \sin y} - \frac{1}{1+\sin x \sin y} \;dx \; dy$
Let's set $\tan \frac{x}{2} = u$
Then,
$\tan x = \frac{2u}{1-u^2}, \; \cos x = \frac{1-u^2}{1+u^2}, \; \sin x = \frac{2u}{1+u^2}, \; dx = \frac{2 du}{1+u^2}$
By substitution,
$\int -2 \cos y \int_{0}^{\pi} \frac{1}{(u-\sin y)^2+(\cos y)^2} - \frac{1}{(u+\sin y)^2+(\cos y)^2} \; dx \; dy$
The first fraction can be integrated by the following substitution.
$u = \cos  y \tan \theta_1 + \sin y, \; du= \cos y \frac{d \theta_1}{\cos \theta^2}$
The second one is also integratable with similar substitution.
$\int -2 \cos y (\int_{x=0}^{x = \pi} \; d \theta_1 \ - \int_{x=0}^{x = \pi} \; d \theta_2) \; dy$
$= \int -2 \cos y \; [\frac{\arctan{(\frac{u-\sin y}{\cos y})} - \arctan{(\frac{u+\sin y}{\cos y}})}{\cos y}]_{0}^{\infty} \; dy$
$= \int -4y \; dy$
$= -2y^2 + c$
$= -2 (\arcsin (\sin y))^2 + c$
$= -2 (\arcsin (\lambda))^2 + c$
It is obvious that the eqaution becomes 0 when $\lambda$ is 0
Therefore, the given equation becomes
$= -2 (\arcsin (\lambda))^2$

Based on my statement previously made the following components are needed for evaluation.
\begin{align}
\ln(1-x) &= - \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{x^n}{n} \\
\int_{0}^{\pi} \sin^{2n-1}\theta \, d\theta &= \frac{4^n}{n \, \binom{2n}{n}} \\
(\sin^{-1}(t))^2 &= \frac{1}{2} \, \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{(2 t)^{2n}}{n^2 \, \binom{2n}{n}}. 
\end{align}
With these components an integral of the form
$$ I = \int_{0}^{\pi} \frac{\ln(1-p^2 \, \sin^{2}(x))}{\sin(x)} \, dx $$
can be evaluated by using
$$ I = - \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{p^{2n}}{n} \, \int_{0}^{\pi} \sin^{2n-1}x \, dx $$
and the rest follows by use of the formulas presented.

This question seems not to meet the standards for the site. Instead of answering it, it would be better to look for a good duplicate target, or help the user by posting comments suggesting improvements. Please also read the meta announcement regarding quality standards.
